# Select the best points where the change is minimal

Tags: math

I would like to select the points where the change is minimal for the problem below, for example, in the graph below, I would select M 900 because after 900, the change is insignificant. I have try to select the points where the change between that point and its right before point is smallest (or smaller than a threshold), in that case, the point at M with 800 is selected which is not the best one in this case.

The y value for the graph below is [27, 14, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Your help is really appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to minimise change before AND change after.

Decide on a function to combine them, then look for the minimum the same way you already do.
Maybe `before + after` or `before*before + after*after`.

Making sure that two large but differently signed changes do not cancel it out is of course important. The second gives you that, but also gets a square into it. Maybe absolute changes are closer to what you are looking for.

Also decide on what to do when several points give you the same minimal change.
I think you want the first one.